# How do I ask whether I got an internship or not?

Tags: interviewing, internship, email

I interviewed for an internship last Thursday (April 20). The woman who was supposed to interview me was running late, so instead another manager-level employee interviewed me. At the end of the interview he told me that he would tell the woman who was supposed to interview me that the interview went very well. I followed up with him via email later to thank him for the interview, and his reply sounded very positive, and he said I would hear from the woman soon. However, a week has passed and I have heard nothing. My school semester is over in two weeks, so I'd like to have an answer before then so I'll have time to find other employment if necessary. My question is: should I email the interviewer or the woman who was supposed to contact me and how would I go about asking whether or not I got the internship?

Comment: e-mail the woman who is supposed to contact you. Tell her you were told you would hear back from her and are curious to know where things stand.

Comment: *"I'd like to have an answer before then so I'll have time to find other employment if necessary"* You should not be waiting for a "no" from one interview before searching for another. Start applying for more positions now, the worst you can say is "sorry, I already accepted another position". The down side to waiting is that somebody else is applying for and interviewing while you are waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send a polite email asking for an update to your point of contact. It could be:
* the recruiter
* manager-level employee; or
* the original interviewee.

The email could be as simple as

```
Dear XXX,

Would you be able to update me on my interview process?

It would help me with planning as my school semester is over in two weeks.

Best regards
tpm900
```

You can add a paragraph about being ready to answer any questions.

*PS. tmp9000 would sound more powerful - a new model ;)*